# Get unique row by single column where duplicates exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following DB table called `messages` with columns:

```
thread_id, sender_id, receiver_id, date
```

Example:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| thread_id | sender_id  | receiver_id |  date       |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------------+
|   1       | 1          |  2          | 11/06/2015  |
|   1       | 2          |  1          | 14/06/2015  |
|   1       | 1          |  2          | 14/06/2015  |
|   1       | 2          |  1          | 20/06/2015  |
|   2       | 1          |  3          | 12/06/2015  |
|   3       | 4          |  2          | 19/06/2015  |
|   3       | 2          |  2          | 20/06/2015  |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need a query that will select unique `thread_id` by earliest date and where `thread_id` exists more than once.

So my desired result would be:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| thread_id |   date       |
+-----------|--------------+
|   1       | 11/06/2015   |
|   3       | 19/06/2015   |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    MIN(date),thread_id 
FROM 
    messages 
GROUP BY 
    thread_id 
HAVING 
    COUNT(thread_id) > 1
```

Comment: you are missing a `group by` not to mention this is not what OP wants

Comment: This is close, and much simpler than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()`

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY thread_id ORDER BY [date]),
        cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY thread_id)
    FROM messages
)
SELECT
    thead_id, [date]
FROM Cte
WHERE
    rn = 1
    AND cc > 1
```